# Protractor - How to separate each test to one file and separate variabiles

Tags: testing, protractor, end-to-end

I have some komplex protractor test written but everything is in one file. 
Where I'm on top of it loading all variabiles like:

```
var userLogin = "John";
```

and after that somewhere in code I use it together.

What I need to do is 
1. Separate all variabiles to aditional file (some config file)
2. Each test to one file

1- I try to make config.js where I add all variabiles and i required it in protractor.conf.js it load correctly problem is that when i use any of this variabiles in some test it's not working (test fail with "userName is not defined")
I know there is a way where i requre config.file in each test script but that's really not best option in my eyes.

2- How can I know what I did in last script if it's separate, like for example how to know I am logged in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple things you can make use of.

> 2) How can I know what I did in last script if it's separate, like for example how to know I am logged in?

This is where [`beforeEach()`, `afterEach()`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown) can help:

> To help a test suite DRY up any duplicated setup and teardown code,
>   Jasmine provides the global beforeEach and afterEach functions. As the
>   name implies, the beforeEach function is called once before each spec
>   in the describe is run, and the afterEach function is called once
>   after each spec.

There are also [`beforeAll()`, `afterAll()` available in jasmine 2](http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-10), or via [`jasmine-beforeAll`](https://github.com/nonplus/jasmine-beforeAll) third-party for jasmine 1:

> The beforeAll function is called only once before all the specs in
>   describe are run, and the afterAll function is called after all specs
>   finish. These functions can be used to speed up test suites with
>   expensive setup and teardown.

---

> 1) I try to make config.js where I add all variabiles and i required
>   it in protractor.conf.js it load correctly problem is that when i use
>   any of this variabiles in some test it's not working (test fail with
>   "userName is not defined") I know there is a way where i requre
>   config.file in each test script but that's really not best option in
>   my eyes.

One option which I've personally used would be to create a `config.js` file with all the *reusable configuration variables* you would need in multiple tests and require the file once - in the protractor config - then set it as a `params` configuration key value:

```
var config = require("./config.js");
exports.config = {
    ...

    params: config,

    ...
};
```

where `config.js` is, for example:

```
var config;
config = {
    user: {
        login: "user",
        password: "password"
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Then, you *would not need to require `config.js` in every test*, but instead, you'll use `browser.params`. For example:

```
expect(browser.params.user.login).toEqual("user");
```

---

Also, if you need some sort of a *global test preparation step*, you can do it in `onPrepare()` function, see [Setting Up the System Under Test](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/f64525265365556fd3c71de296ec54b31c846c8f/docs/system-setup.md#setting-up-the-system-under-test). Example configuration that performs a "global" login step is available [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/withLoginConf.js).

And an another quick note: you can have *custom globally defined variables* (like built-in `browser` or `protractor`), set them using `global` in `onPrepare`. For example, I've defined `protractor.ExpectedConditions` as a custom global variable:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
}
```

Then, in tests, don't require anything, `EC variable would be available in the scope, e.g.:

```
browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(scope.page.dropdown), 5000)
```

---

Also, organizing your tests using ["Page Object Pattern"](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md) would also help to solve the *reusability and modularity* problem.

Comment: Thank you @alecxe, nice answer as always. I will try your tips tomorow. But for now it looks really great

Comment: @Andurit thanks, sorry it is probably too much information. Just wanted to point out as much relevant as possible.